# Powershell parsing a properties file that contains colons

Tags: powershell, hashtable, properties-file

If I have a .properties file that contains directories (which contain colons):

```
some_dir=f:\some\dir\etc
another_dir=d:\dir\some\bin
```

and then use ConvertFrom-StringData to convert Key=Value pairs from said properties file to a hash table:

```
$props_file = Get-Content "F:\dir\etc\props.properties"
$props = ConvertFrom-StringData ($props_file)
$the_dir = $props.'some_dir'
Write-Host $the_dir
```

Powershell throws an error (doesn't like colons):

```
ConvertFrom-StringData : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'    required by parameter 'StringData'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:3 char:32
+ $props = ConvertFrom-StringData <<<<  ($props_file)
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertFrom-StringData],     ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :     CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromStringDataCommand
```

How do you get round this? I'd like to be able to just refer to the directories using the . notation:

```
$props.'some_dir'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Colons have nothing to do with the error you get. And yes, it can be achieved using ConvertFrom-StringData but, as already mentioned, you're feeding it an array instead of a string. Moreover, you need paths with double backslashes in your file because single backslashes are interpreted as escape characters.

Here's how to fix your code:

```
# Reading file as a single string:
$sRawString = Get-Content "F:\dir\etc\props.properties" | Out-String

# The following line of code makes no sense at first glance 
# but it's only because the first '\\' is a regex pattern and the second isn't. )
$sStringToConvert = $sRawString -replace '\\', '\\'

# And now conversion works.
$htProperties = ConvertFrom-StringData $sStringToConvert

$the_dir = $htProperties.'some_dir'
Write-Host $the_dir
```

Comment: You only get the `Unrecognized escape sequence` error if the _value_ has an unescaped slash. If the _key_ has a slash it is ignored. Hence the approach above is sadly unusable if you will have slashes in your keys too.

Answer (score 3):

`ConvertFrom-StringData` expects a string and you are feeding it an array `Get-Content` cmdlet. Change `$props_file` to:

```powershell
$props_file = (Get-Content "F:\dir\etc\props.properties") | Out-String
```

and you will get another error:

```powershell
ConvertFrom-StringData : parsing "f:\some\dir\etc" - Unrecognized escape sequence \s.
```

You can get around it like so:

```powershell
$props_file = Get-Content "F:\dir\etc\props.properties"
$props = @{}
$props_file | % {
    $s = $_ -split "="
    $props.Add($s[0],$s[1])
}
$the_dir = $props.'some_dir'
Write-Host $the_dir
```

Result:

```powershell
f:\some\dir\etc
```

Answer (score 3):

You could parse the file as it's loaded, and populate an empty hashtable line-by-line.

```
$props = @{}
GC "F:\dir\etc\props.properties" | %{$props.add($_.split('=')[0],$_.split('=')[1])}
```